# Matlab, How to generate random lines without any intersections?

Tags: matlab

I just wanna generate many lines at least 6 units along with specific orientations and directions (the lines are the elements of pyramids--i.e each line has 60 degree orientation) in a domain without any intersections between them..
How to do that ??

I made one but it was not efficient, Just generated 100 lines then after generating them I tested the intersection and deleted any intersection lines and I got only 5 to 10 remaining lines.. But I need around 100 or 200, actually it's a generic code

```
%Pattern_x, Pattern_y , and Pattern_z are the x, y,and z positions of any mesh and dx, dy, dy the increments of x, y, z and the cube element is C

x=zeros(C*C*C,1);

j=randi([1,(C*C*C)],No_of_lines+10*C,1);
ii=datasample(j,No_of_lines,'Replace',false);
x(ii)=1;

lines=zeros(No_of_lines,2,3);

for i=1:6:length(ii)
    z1=ii(i);
vx1=Pattern_x(z1);
vy1=Pattern_y(z1);
vz1=Pattern_z(z1);

vx2=Pattern_x(z1)+2*dx;
vy2=Pattern_y(z1)-2*dy;
vz2=Pattern_z(z1)+4*dz;

vx3=Pattern_x(z1)-2*dx;
vy3=Pattern_y(z1)+2*dy;
vz3=Pattern_z(z1)-4*dz;

lines(i,1,:)=[vx2 vy2 vz2];
lines(i,2,:)=[vx3 vy3 vz3];

end
for i=2:6:length(ii)
    z2=ii(i);
vx1=Pattern_x(z2);
vy1=Pattern_y(z2);
vz1=Pattern_z(z2);

vx2=Pattern_x(z2)-2*dx;
vy2=Pattern_y(z2)+2*dy;
vz2=Pattern_z(z2)+4*dz;

vx3=Pattern_x(z2)+2*dx;
vy3=Pattern_y(z2)-2*dy;
vz3=Pattern_z(z2)-4*dz;

lines(i,1,:)=[vx2 vy2 vz2];
lines(i,2,:)=[vx3 vy3 vz3];

end
for i=3:6:length(ii)
    z3=ii(i);
vx1=Pattern_x(z3);
vy1=Pattern_y(z3);
vz1=Pattern_z(z3);

vx2=Pattern_x(z3)+2*dx;
vy2=Pattern_y(z3)+2*dy;
vz2=Pattern_z(z3)+4*dz;

vx3=Pattern_x(z3)-2*dx;
vy3=Pattern_y(z3)-2*dy;
vz3=Pattern_z(z3)-4*dz;

lines(i,1,:)=[vx2 vy2 vz2];
lines(i,2,:)=[vx3 vy3 vz3];

end
for i=4:6:length(ii)
    z4=ii(i);
vx1=Pattern_x(z4);
vy1=Pattern_y(z4);
vz1=Pattern_z(z4);

vx2=Pattern_x(z4)-2*dx;
vy2=Pattern_y(z4)-2*dy;
vz2=Pattern_z(z4)+4*dz;

vx3=Pattern_x(z4)+2*dx;
vy3=Pattern_y(z4)+2*dy;
vz3=Pattern_z(z4)-4*dz;

lines(i,1,:)=[vx2 vy2 vz2];
lines(i,2,:)=[vx3 vy3 vz3];

end

for i=5:6:length(ii)
    z5=ii(i);
vx1=Pattern_x(z5);
vy1=Pattern_y(z5);
vz1=Pattern_z(z5);

vx2=Pattern_x(z5)+4*dx;
vy2=Pattern_y(z5);
vz2=Pattern_z(z5);

vx3=Pattern_x(z5)-4*dx;
vy3=Pattern_y(z5);
vz3=Pattern_z(z5);

lines(i,1,:)=[vx2 vy2 vz2];
lines(i,2,:)=[vx3 vy3 vz3];

end

for i=6:6:length(ii)
    z6=ii(i);
vx1=Pattern_x(z6);
vy1=Pattern_y(z6);
vz1=Pattern_z(z6);

vx2=Pattern_x(z6);
vy2=Pattern_y(z6)+4*dy;
vz2=Pattern_z(z6);

vx3=Pattern_x(z6);
vy3=Pattern_y(z6)-4*dy;
vz3=Pattern_z(z6);

lines(i,1,:)=[vx2 vy2 vz2];
lines(i,2,:)=[vx3 vy3 vz3];

end

kk = No_of_lines;
Zeta = zeros(No_of_lines,1);
for A=1:kk
for B=2:kk

    nA = dot(cross(lines(B,2,:)-lines(B,1,:),lines(A,1,:)-lines(B,1,:)),cross(lines(A,2,:)-lines(A,1,:),lines(B,2,:)-lines(B,1,:)));
    nB = dot(cross(lines(A,2,:)-lines(A,1,:),lines(A,1,:)-lines(B,1,:)),cross(lines(A,2,:)-lines(A,1,:),lines(B,2,:)-lines(B,1,:)));
    d = dot(cross(lines(A,2,:)-lines(A,1,:),lines(B,2,:)-lines(B,1,:)),cross(lines(A,2,:)-lines(A,1,:),lines(B,2,:)-lines(B,1,:)));
    A0 = lines(A,1,:) + (nA/d)*(lines(A,2,:)-lines(A,1,:));
    B0 = lines(B,1,:) + (nB/d)*(lines(B,2,:)-lines(B,1,:));

    if A0 - B0 == 0

        Zeta(B) = B;

    end




end
end
   f=find(Zeta~=0);
    lines(f,:,:)=[];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought, but what if you randomly generate points (say 200) and connect them to their nearest neighbor?  Then delete any linestring that is connected to a second linestring (but only one of each pair).  Does it matter how long the lines are?

Comment: Actually, I did !! 
I generated random points and at each point I put different line and so on but I can't get the number of required lines without intersections

Comment: Why are there only 5 lines left?  It seems like there should be more... What if you detected the `middle` linestring, in case there are more than two connected.  So delete every other linestring.  Something like .---.--.----.---.--. would become .---.  .----.   .--.

Comment: By the way, the lines should have specific orientation that's what i do, but how to put these number of lines in this domain without intersections !!

Comment: What do you mean by specific orientation?  Can you please edit that information into your original question?

Comment: Unfortunatly, the line should by continuous and has a certain length

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124998/discussion-between-user203212546-and-khaled-khafagy).

Answer (score 1):

What I see at the end of your code is that you find all the lines that have an intersection with any other lines, and you get rid of them all, right?

It is not the most efficient way, because: Imagine line `A` and line `B` have intersection with each other and with no other lines. You are removing both of them, while actually you can keep one of them!

A much more efficient way would be to:

1. Generate many lines randomly,
2. Evaluate **the number of overlaps per line**,
3. Sort them accordingly,
4. Remove the top *few* percent of the list,
5. Repeat the steps 2 to 4 until you have no overlap.

This way you will remove efficiently and keep more.

Comment: I got what are you talking about but at the end of the day, I need no any intersection between any lines so I think the result will be the same.. And, i tried to loop more than tens but the results are not acceptable

Comment: You are wrong, the result won't be the same. Imagine line `A` and line `B` have intersection with each other and with no other line. You are removing both of them, while actually you can keep one of them!

Comment: No, I delete one of them :)
 A is a line and B is another line and I store B when the condition gonna be correct to delete B only

Comment: Not really! You are finding such `B`, but you are looping over all pairs of lines. Eventually you are going to check the same pair twice but in reversed order. Then you also mark `A` for deletion.

Comment: Ok, what i am trying to say is that I check line with others and delete any intersections with this line then I do the same with the second line and so on even I come back to first one I will not find any one get intersecting with it... in other wards A and B are lines if B intersects A, I will delete B and go on to other lines and A will not be have any intersection with B.

Comment: Maybe that is what you want to do, but if you look at the very last lines of your code, you will see that `f=find(Zeta~=0); lines(f,:,:)=[];` is placed outside the nested `for` loop. Lines are deleted after all pairs are checked.

Comment: Yeah, You are right, I will check it.
Thanks a million